# refresh form_token with refresh page

Tags: 9, security, csrf

Unfortunately, the form_token does not change when I refresh the form pages.
Doesn't this cause abuse and security risks?
Can anyone explain what Drupal does for CSRF in all its forms?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As the definition of CSRF says

> A CSRF token is a secure random token (e.g., synchronizer token or
> challenge token) that is used to prevent CSRF attacks. The token needs
> to be unique per user session and should be of large random value to
> make it difficult to guess. A CSRF secure application assigns a unique
> CSRF token for every user session.

it protects BE to be sure the posted that to the BE comes from a form generated by BE unless anybody can post data to BE from any source.

for example in a login form, a hacker could write a code to try several combinations ( of course drupal has a max retry policy which prevents users to try the wrong password more than 5 times and there is flood detection in drupal that prevent brute force attacking). But still, forms without CSRF protection are good places for bots and spammers to post data to the side several times.

So it's better if your forms are open to anonymous protect them [honeypot](https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot) and a human detection solution ( captcha, [Recaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha), Recaptcha 3 math captcha, etc).

additionally, having [Security Kit module](https://www.drupal.org/project/seckit) make it more secure.

**Update part after I noticed it's happening for logged in users**
for the reasons I mentioned above, particularly to have better caching functionalities, for an anonymous user, it does not get refreshed.
**But for logged-in user** after some checking in the code level I figure out it's not a bug.

it's generated based on the form_id and until you have not submitted the form it will be the same and refreshing does not generate a new one. So, `form_token` and `form_build_id` are things that protects form from.

for reference and get more take a look on :

```
    // Add a token, based on either #token or form_id, to any form displayed to
  // authenticated users. This ensures that any submitted form was actually
  // requested previously by the user and protects against cross site request
  // forgeries.
  // This does not apply to programmatically submitted forms. Furthermore,
  // since tokens are session-bound and forms displayed to anonymous users are
  // very likely cached, we cannot assign a token for them.
  // During installation, there is no $user yet.
  // Form constructors may explicitly set #token to FALSE when cross site
  // request forgery is irrelevant to the form, such as search forms.
  if ($form_state
    ->isProgrammed() || isset($form['#token']) && $form['#token'] === FALSE) {
    unset($form['#token']);
  }
  else {
    $form['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'user.roles:authenticated';
    if ($user && $user
      ->isAuthenticated()) {

      // Generate a public token and placeholder based on the form ID.
      $placeholder = 'form_token_placeholder_' . Crypt::hashBase64($form_id);
      $form['#token'] = $placeholder;
      $form['form_token'] = [
        '#id' => Html::getUniqueId('edit-' . $form_id . '-form-token'),
        '#type' => 'token',
        '#default_value' => $placeholder,
        // Form processing and validation require this value. Ensure the
        // submitted form value appears literally, regardless of custom #tree
        // and #parents being set elsewhere.
        '#parents' => [
          'form_token',
        ],
```

**Reference :** https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormBuilder.php/function/FormBuilder%3A%3AprepareForm/9.3.x

Comment: Thank you dear @Yuseferi . But my question is why the token does not change on refresh page and is this a Drupal bug? Or Drupal controls the CSRF with other methods, such as the use of cookies or other common methods

Comment: @reza I believe it's not a bug. because adding CSRF to all anonymous form cause some issues with caching. and it intentionally does not generate CSRF for anonymous forms. of course, there are some session cookies to keep trace of user but it does not engage in form submission, and form submission can be easily imitated by a script. it's is the reason usually faced lots of spam on anonymous forms.

Comment: I do not mean an anonymous user. As far as I know CSRF is valid for authenticated users and this method was created to prevent unauthorized sending

Comment: @reza answer updated

Answer (score 2):

> Drupal's anti-CSRF token works by combining information that is secret to the site, the action, and the individual user into a hashed value sent in the HTML of the page.

From https://www.drupal.org/node/2319205

Comment: "and the individual user". It's a session based thing. That's why it doesn't change on just a cache flush.